# Searching for a jQuery date selector plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

im looking for a birthdate selector, but not in a datepicker style; instead i need 3 comboboxes, day list should be updated depending on selected month. Any ideas?

Comment: How about...
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: this sounds pretty easy to code yourself

Comment: sounds easy but there are some factors to consider. months with 28, 29, 30 and 31 days (depending on year every 4 years, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There may or may not be a JQuery version of what you describe, but why not just create the functionality yourself using comboboxes? It doesn't seem like it would be that difficult to implement.

Comment: so far it looks like i will have to do that. i was looking for a quick solution out there :s -- i'll post the solution once its done.